# apt over SSH hangs on my Raspberry Pi

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, aptitude, apt, headless

I have a very strange phenomenon on my R-Pi. If I run either `apt` or `aptitude` via a remote SSH shell, the processor jumps to 100% (top shows it's `apt`). If I connect my keyboard and run it on an interactive shell (say, by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>) and run `apt` in there it works.

When running via SSH I let it run for more than 30 minutes, but it did not continue at all.

Any ideas?

Note: I am running Raspbian Wheezy and have not yet tested with Arch/pacman.

Comment: I've never had that issue on my pi, running current raspbian. I tend to run apt/aptitude inside `tmux` when I'm remotely connected though.

Comment: Try updating directly from your pi using `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, `sudo apt-get update`, and `sudo apt-get install upgrade`. If this doesn't help and if you don't get any good answers, try migrating your question to [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @zeldarulez Will do! I'll try it this evening. And thanks for the other SE link. I did not know it existed :)